# Python: How To Regex Out 2 Areas Within The Same Line?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, expression

```
xpath(//Edge[@Id='3' or @Id='74'])
```

Hi, I wish to ask how to do simulatenous regex.

I want to extract out both of those numbers: 3 and 74

i have my regex pattern too `regex_1 = re.compile(".*Id='([0-9]*)'.*")`

The intent is to regex out 3 and 74, and then store each result to a dictionary property, they will be still within the same key,values pair.

Comment: If you can use the PyPi regex module `(?:xpath\(//|\G(?!^))[^@\r\n]*@[^\r\n=]*='(\d+)'` or `(?:xpath\(//|\G(?!^))[^@\r\n]*@[^\r\n=]*='\K\d+(?=')` https://regex101.com/r/dHe5yM/1

Comment: hi. this regex expression looks really long just for the job. i dont think my boss will approve such a regex in our script.

Comment: It is not really long but is also takes the xpath part into account. They are actually 2 variations of the same pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the id values, and inserting them as values to a new dictionary structure:

```
import re

text = "xpath(//Edge[@Id='3' or @Id='74'])"

pattern = re.compile(r".*Id='(\d+)'" * 2)

res = pattern.search(text)

print(res.groups())

new_storage = {
    "first_id": res.group(1),
    "second_id": res.group(2)
}

print(new_storage)
```

Results in:

```
('3', '74')
{'first_id': '3', 'second_id': '74'}
```

Comment: hi your pattern is ingenious. so you simply extended the pattern abit more to explicitly include the other 'Id' ?

Comment: Yes. This pattern will capture both id values, which can then be extracted by the .groups() method subsequently. You could also just do: pattern = re.compile(r".*Id='(\d+)'" * 2)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to extract all numeric values as a list into a pre-defined key? Whould the following work for you?

```
import re
s = "xpath(//Edge[@Id='3' or @Id='74'])"
d = {'id': re.findall(r"(?<=@Id=')\d+", s)}
print(d)
```

Returns:

```
{'id': ['3', '74']}
```

---

Or, if they must be `int` type:

```
import re
s = "xpath(//Edge[@Id='3' or @Id='74'])"
d = {'id': list(map(int,re.findall(r"(?<=@Id=')\d+", s)))}
print(d)
```

Returns:

```
{'id': [3, 74]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/modules/) first matching the xpath part of the pattern followed by using the  `\G` anchor to get iterative matches. The digit is captured in group 1.

```
(?:xpath\(//|\G(?!^))[^@]*@[^=]*='(\d+)'
```

*In parts*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `xpath\(//` Match `xpath(//`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close group
- `[^@]*@` Match any char except @, then match the `@`
- `[^=]*='` Match any char except the =, then match the `=` and the opening `'`
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `'` Match `'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq59S7/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##Lc1NC8IgAMbxu5/CvKgr2mFBsJDtEtFn8AUG2iYsFedhQd/dRLo9D/zgHz5p8a7L2b6DjwlGM5sdgDClZKKDDEZEhn4vfxGkbb/iQYaDopSrUTYjV0w2DBOhjxQjsBWPqi30rmfDx6dmuMPQR1jn9YIlRSBE6xKprfPLOj2tK/knT3Cj9JbzDw)

Example code

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:xpath\(//|\G(?!^))[^@]*@[^=]*='(\d+)'"
s = "xpath(//Edge[@Id='3' or @Id='74'])"
print(regex.findall(pattern, s));
```

Output

```
['3', '74']
```